# Is there an Amp + Volt-meter on a chip or should I use the Arduino Analog?

Tags: arduino, voltage, measurement, amperage

I'm thinking of building a general purpose battery charger. It would charge LiPo packs, 9V, AA, AAA, etc...

I've been doing a bit of Googling and read that the internal Phone charging circuits tend to do top up cycles, after the charge is at optimal level (optimal level being some 70% or 80% to give better life span to packs)

So is there a simple chip that has a Volt-meter in parallel and an Amp-meter in series, with small load, that can interface with the Arduino?

Or should I just use the Analog inputs, as long as I protect the AVR from too much current?

Thanks

Comment: `as long as I protect the AVR from too much current`
I don't know what you mean by that. Analog input are voltage inputs and have a high internal resistance (quite like your DMM on the volts setting). That means: there will only flow low currents.

Comment: @Gustavo - I think you might need to do a bit more research before designing this product.  Your question is overly broad; we can't teach you the things you need to know about battery charging, voltage measurement, current measurement, and input protection in one question.

Comment: @0x6d64 When you say `Analog input are voltage inputs and have a high internal resistance` does that mean that I could measure the voltage of a 1800mAh rechargeable battery pack while it was being charged at whatever current it needs?

Comment: @KevinVermeer Indeed you are right about the fact that I'm being overly broad. I have this, probably stupid, way of building my projects one little "island" of functionality at a time and test each "island" with the other "islands" until I get a full working project.
At the moment I'm focusing on this little mental "island" that is the possibility of a discreet element with the integrated functions of a voltmeter and an ammeter.
So, I'm really sorry about throwing you guys off like this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can't measure amperes directly with an analog input. You might use a component called "shunt" (basically a resistor with low value) and an opamp for amplifying the small output of the shunt. However, there are other methods for measuring currents (e.g. using the hall effect).
2. There are *many* dedicated ICs for building battery chargers out there. Some of them will be universal for many battery chemistries, I guess.

Comment: E.g. [Maxim Semi](http://www.maxim-ic.com/products/power/battery_management/) battery chargers, National Semi, and numerous others also offer their own product lines as well. I don't recommend rolling-you-own Lithium charger, due to safety hazards (fire, shock).

Comment: The BQ2000T from Texas Instruments is an incredibly popular one, mainly due to its relative simplicity.

Comment: @mctylr and Matt: from your comments I think that I can now try and think about the enclosure design and give one of those a go on my breadboard :)
Thanks!